# Passwords Plus - "Application has stopped working"

Tags: windows-10, password-management

I have been using this application, Passwords Plus, for a long time - since XP and Palm.

It worked well with Win10 until last week, when I started getting the message above ("Application has stopped working").

I have gone to the company's website, DataViz, and their solutions have not worked.

When this first happened, I checked their website for solutions. They acknowledge this as a common error. Solutions tried are:

- They suggested right clicking the program icon and running as an administrator
- editing permissions on the Security tab for the "Documents" folder, to allow all permissions.
- Next they sent a reg file, asking that this be added to the registry
- then they asked me to re-install the program.

None of this has made any difference - the program still crashes on opening.

Questions:

- Has anyone else encountered & solved this error?
- Any suggestions for things to try?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the solutions you've already tried, and what the results were, that way we don't suggest things you've already tried.  E.g.: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application?

Comment: Here is the link to the support website:
[Passwords Plus Support](http://support.dataviz.com/support_index_pp.html)

Comment: If you create a new Windows user, and then log in as that user, does the program run as expected (ie: without that error)?

Comment: It is solved now (see answer), so I do not need to pursue that angle.  However, thanks for the suggestion -  I will remember it for the next a similar situation arises.

Answer (score 1):

After several exchanges with the support team at DataViz, they suggested renaming the subject database and restarting the application.  This forced it to refresh, and re-download the original database from the cloud version.  This has worked and all is good.
Dan